# Convert object as string to json

Tags: json, sobject, string, deserialize, serialization

I have an object which is converted to string in a text field. How can I convert this to a JSON string.

String of object:

```
Profile:[UID=, crmId=0000o00002XXXXxXXX, email=top@top.com, firstname=null, lastname=test]
```

I tried JSON.serialize(textfield); but this only sets "" arount the text

I want to convert this to the following:

```
{ "email" : "top@top.com",
"crmId" : "0000o00002XXXXxXXX",
"firstname" : "null",
"lastname" : "test",
"UID" : ""
}
```

Comment: any chance the supplier of this info can preserve the original Json so you don't need to go through this conversion?

Comment: @cropredy This could only be possible in this case if the object cloud be saved in a salesforce field but as far I know this ist possible, any suggestions?

Comment: Is the ID of the real object in this text string representation of the object? Are you able to just query it and then serialize the actual object record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily parse your **String** into **Map** and then serialize **Map** itself.

Here is an example how to do it:

```
String toMap = 'Profile:[UID=, crmId=0000o00002XXXXxXXX, email=top@top.com, firstname=null, lastname=test]';

Map<String, String> ans = new Map<String, String>();
String actualValues = toMap.substringAfter(':');
actualValues = actualValues.substring(1, actualValues.length()-1);


for (String val : actualValues.split(', ')) {
    ans.put(val.substringBefore('='), val.substringAfter('='));
}

String jsonString = JSON.serialize(ans);
system.debug(jsonString);
```